# React MaterialUI DataGrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, columnsorting

I am using DataGrid from MaterialUI in React to build a table which is sortable.  It all works great but I have added an extra row called totals to the bottom of the table which shows the total of each column.

https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid

The problem arises when you click on a column to sort the rows the totals row also gets sorted.  Is there an easy to prevent this? I want the totals row to stay on the bottom when the table gets sorted.

Thanks